# Team windows on separate screen?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Is there a way that I can have all PROJECT MANAGEMENT related panes TOGETHER in one window on the 2nd screen?

I mean team explorer, task and query windows, etc.
Not just "floating panes", I want several panes, docked in ONE SEPARATE WINDOW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dock panel to panel. This creates new window.
E.g.:  detach one pane you want, then detach 2nd and drag-drop it to the first (you'll see docking helper).

Comment: Hey thanks!! I found you need VS 2013 - **Update 4**, then you get a true separate window, works like a charm!